# How do you cache a file client-side such that the browser stops even bothering to request it again?

Tags: http, caching, http-caching

I send back an image with the following HTTP response header:

```
Cache-Control: private,max-age=86400
```

My understanding is that the browser *should not even ask for this file* for 24 hours (86,400 = 60s * 60m * 24h).

What I'm seeing on subsequent requests is that it still asks for the file, but gets back a "304 Not Modified."  This is good, but I want to remove even that request/response.

What header is required to prevent the browser from even bothering to ask for the file, and just have it blindly use the file it has in local cache, until that file expires?

Comment: Same behavior on all browsers? It should be enough with that :-s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all really depends on how you're testing this. On Firefox 3.6 and IE8, clicking on a link and then on a link that move you back to the first page will use the cache correctly with max-age. Hitting the Return key again in the URL field will show the same behavior.

However, hitting F5 will ask again for the file but allows 304 responses.

Hitting Ctrl+F5 will always ask again for the file, with Cache-Control and Pragma set to no-cache, forcing a 200 response.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I didn't realize that hitting F5 was the problem.  When I tested using a simple link click (so, a simple GET), it works as I expected it to.

Answer (score 0):

This simply can't be done reliably in HTML < 5.

You could use [client side storage](http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/) in HTML5 or use a browser extension such as [Gears](http://gears.google.com/) to provide this functionality.

Comment: what do you mean with "can't be done reliably"? There is no warranty that the browser will keep the resource on the cache until the expiration time, but it should keep it for a "while" at least :-D